# How can I find what a Windows PC thinks its name is, given its IP?

Tags: windows, shell, script, cmd.exe, hostname

How can I find out what a remote Windows PC thinks its host name is, given its IP? From Windows cmd.exe or a Linux shell.

I'm not interested what a DNS server thinks the host name is for an IP, just what the machine which responds to an IP address thinks its name is.

I do not want to use RDP but do have access to an administrative user on the destination PCs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:
`wmic /node:<your_ip_here> computersystem get name,domain`

or if you prefer powershell:
`Get-WmiObject -co <your_ip_here> win32_computersystem -property name,domain |format-list -property name,domain`

Both will allow you to query a list instead of single PC and specify specific credentials if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

```
nbtstat -a IP-Address
```

Example: nbtstat -a 192.168.1.1

Comment: I have marked the other answer as 'correct' as I believe that's closer to my intent. However yours is simpler and I've never known a Windows machine to offer a different NetBIOS name to its machine name so this is also a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ping` with its `-a` switch to resolve IP addresses to hostnames.

```
ping -a 192.168.1.1
```